# Geocoder not returning Address of some loction

Tags: android, google-geocoder

I have the issue with some location that donot return me the address while other returns me the address i have issue with the following address

List addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(
        "568 S. Coy St., Kansas City, Kansas, 66105", 1);

List addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(
        "10075 Bauer Rd., St. Louis, Missouri, 63128", 1);

I just try to get the Address with the hardcode string but i got failure to get the address , While if i remove the initial address it return me the address of location while if i put this on the web page of google map it shows me the marker on the actual location where the place is.